# Microsoft Visual Studio Arrays at Runtime

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012, displayobject

My instructions are: "Create a form that will display a running total of numbers a user enters." - to do this I've created a form with two text boxes (one for the number of values in the array and the other for the values in the array), a button to display it, and a label for it all to be displayed it. The issue is, is that my values aren't showing up - at all. My code is as below:

(** NOTE: I'm attempting to get the array to display in my label. txtInput is the inputted values and txtArrayValues is the number of elements.)

```
namespace Running_Total
{
    public partial class frmEnter : Form
    {
        public frmEnter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtArrayValues.Text);

        string[] strArray;
        strArray = new string[intNumber];

        int i;
        string j = "";

        for (i = 0; i < intNumber; i++)
        {
            j = Convert.ToString(txtInput.Text);
            strArray[i] += j;
        }

        lblDisplay.Text = strArray + " ";
    }
}
```

}

Before, when I'd put `lblDisplay.Text += j + " ";`, it showed up in the label, but didn't pay any attention to the amount of elements the code was supposed to have. (Edit: this no longer works in my code.) (As is indicated in the title, I'm working with C# through Microsoft Visual Studio.)

Comment: By the way, in your for loop you can instantiate i on the fly like this `for(int i = 0; i < intNumber; i++)`

Comment: ok what was in "txtInput.text" ? you wont need to convert it to string, it is a string. lets say you write in txtinput "frog" .. your label of j + " "j will say frog, so your display will be "frog " .. you have copied the same name into each of your array items, but its only alive during that button click, so, after the buttonclick has finished, your array is gone, and all you have to show for it is the context of an inputbox + a space in your label - the code is doing exactly what you asked

Comment: @BugFinder I put in numeric values for the elements, like the number 5- converting it was left over from when I had the array in the double data type (I've deleted that from my code now that you brought it to my attention)... How do I get the array to display in the label, then?

Comment: @Naima to get the array to display, in a for loop (for example `for(int i = 0; i < strArray.GetLength(0); i++)) you should do `lblDisplay.Text += strArray[i];`

Comment: Hmm, I can't understand what you have been asked (what they mean with a "running total of numbers"?), but your code will do just anything, you create a new array each time the button is clicked, so there's no storage between calls to the click button, and the array will have all it's items initialized to the value of j...

Comment: @Gusman I assume he meant he wanted the user to input numbers, which would be stored in an array, but displayed on the form (which is what we'd discussed in the notes). I literally don't have any more instruction. Is there any way to get the array to store it outside of the button click?

Comment: What exactly you mean by "running total of numbers"? Looking at your code I don't see any persistence. Scope of everything in your code starts and ends within button click routine. I would appreciate if you can clear your objective.

Comment: Yes, create the array at class level instead at function level. Also, you will need to use lblDisplay.Text = string.Join(" ", strArray); to show all the values in the array.

Comment: @MukeshAdhvaryu I'm trying to display the numbers the user inputs - I was told to use an array to accomplish this. The button click was supposed to be used to display it, but I don't know where else to put the code.

Comment: Might it be that a running total is the sum of all numbers that the user inputs? adding it up each time the user presses the display button?

Comment: @MongZhu the lesson is on arrays, so I think he's specifically referring to displaying the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strongly depends on the fashion how the user inputs the numbers.

1) If he fills the textbox once with numbers and then presses the button to display them in the other box, it would suffice to use a string array catch the input and add it to the textbox or label that displays it. If he deletes the numbers in the input box and types new ones you could just repeat this step

```
namespace Running_Total
{
    public partial class frmEnter : Form
    {
         // declare your Array here
         string [] array = new string[1000];
         int count = 0;

         public frmEnter()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             // save input
             array[count] = inputTextBox.Text;
             count++;

             // display whole input
             string output = "";
             for(int i = 0;i < count; i++)
             {
                 output += array[i];                     
             }
             // write it the texbox
             outputTextBox.Text = output;

         }
}
```

Does that answer your question or do you have another input pattern in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I realized that you want to display same number enteted in txtInput text repeatedly up to as many times as a number entered in a txtArrayValues.Text. So for example txtArrayValues. Text = "5" and txtInput.Text="2", your code will yield result "2,2,2,2,2". If that is what you want then the following code will achieve that.

```
using System.Linq;
    namespace Running_Total
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int len, num;
                if (int.TryParse(txtArrayValues.Text, out len) &&
int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out num))
                {
                    lblDisplay.Text = string.Join(",", new string[len].Select(x => txtInput.Text));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```